# Object appearance changes after Scale transformation applied

Tags: transforms

I have human model imported into the scene:
[image: Human model **before** Scale transformation applied]

When I select it, click <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and choose **Scale**, it's appearance changes to this:

[image: Human model **after** Scale transformation applied]

Is it just the visual change? How can I make the model remain the same after applying **Scale** transformation?

Comment: Was the scale negative before applying ?

Comment: @MrZak it is negative indeed. **-0.001**

Comment: @MrZak rescaled the scene to make it positive and now it applies without changing object's appearance. Thank you!

Comment: Go ahead and add that as an answer to your own question to show that it's solved. I'm not sure why you "rescaled the scene".

Comment: @MrZak based on your question about model probably having negative scale, I suggested that it was the cause, so I rescaled it (all the objects on the scene to keep proportions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object had negative scale. Before applying scale, hit <kbd>S</kbd> to rescale it to get positive values or hit <kbd>N</kbd> to bring **Transform Properties Panel** and retype scale there. Object will mirror around it's axis, by the way.